# How rake test: figures out classpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to find out how rake test:units figures out classpath to get all the classes in my application on classpath. Where to start? Which files to browse or what to read/understand first?

Basic gems and their's classes are loaded from ruby/lib directory thats obvious, others are looked up from places that are specified by -I switch for "ruby" to tell ruby where to look for files. Now I guess there is some much more elaborate dynamic loading of files by rake/rails in addition to that to look for rails app classes and unit tests. But I don't know where to start digging to understand it.

Is there some way in ruby perhaps to print out all locations that are currently scanned for files?